# Unwanted spaces added between characters in string

Tags: mysql, xml, ms-access, character-encoding

I have a Microsoft Access front end linked to a MySQL database on a linux server.  All of the varchar columns in the table are operating normally except for the most recent one I've implemented.

When I attempt to save text to the new column "Filename" (varchar(200)), somewhere between inputting the data using MS Access and the data being recorded to the MySQL database, a space is inserted between every single character of the string. For instance, if I enter in
"/home/username/folder/filename.xml", the value recorded in the table is  "/ h o m e / u s e r n a m e / f o l d e r / f i l e n a m e . x m l".

Before I created this table, I was attempting to modify a different columns character encoding (between ascii, utf-8, and other file types) to try and retrieve an actual xml file instead of just a file name and location. Perhaps I messed up something with that particular column. I have tried restarting the computer and deleting and re-adding the column in both MS Access and on the MySQL database itself.

**What could be causing the generation of the extra spaces, and how can I fix the issue without a cheap solution of parsing the string differently?** I want to tackle this at the root of the problem.

Information: MySQL database using UTF-8 encoding as the table default with the Innodb engine.

Comment: Well, after deleting all relevant columns in both access and mysql and restarting the PC and SSH connection 3 times, the issue is gone. Thanks for the help anyways.  Could an admin close this question (unless they think it might ever be useful to someone else)?

Comment: you should delete this question. not have it closed.. you can remove the question yourself. and you should. because this error cannot be reproduced anymore so it wouldn't be helpful for anyone else

Comment: Ok, I want sure on the proper procedure for that.

Answer (score 0):

try running this. it should remove the whitespace (assuming you have a unique identifier for each row called id)

```
UPDATE table t, 
(   SELECT 
        id, 
        REPLACE(filename , ' ' , '' ) as filename 
    FROM table
) t1
SET t.filename = t1.filename WHERE t.id = t1.id
```

for us to help you with the insert we would need a lot more information than what you provided.

Comment: Yes, I believe this would patch the issue. However, I'm trying to find out why the whitespace is there in the first place. It's only happening in my most recently added column, not in any of the others.

Comment: @pheidlauf there is no code in your post.. there is no way we can help you without the proper information.. look at how to ask a question in the help center if you don't know what to put in there.. but we need data, we need the code structure.. what your attempt is, and what your expected results should be

Comment: I was hoping the situation with added spaces would be unique enough that someone would recognize the cause without my code. I will post detailed code for this when I am back at work tomorrow.

Comment: @pheidlauf maybe someone has encountered this exact issue.. but its not that likely.. if they notice and post an answer i'll be happy to remove mine ;)

Comment: I think your answer is useful, I just don't want to put a "bandaid" on a project I'm about to turn over to my supervisor. :)

Comment: @pheidlauf I completely understand :) I'll take a look at the code when you have it up there :) hopefully its a simple fix

Comment: @pheidlauf how do you send the data to the linux backend? is it with a form?

Comment: I've linked the tables into MS Access using the ODBC plugin, and am inputting the data with forms.

Comment: can you debug on the client side to see what the data looks like right before it finishes the request?

Comment: also on the server side all languages have a string trim method that can be used for whitespaces... so if you add the trim before you do the insert it should fix the issue

Comment: I've tried debugging on Access, but all of the settings I've seen look completely standard. Actually, the strangest thing I've noticed is that the data is displayed correctly in access the form, even after the white space has been added. MySQL select queries are where the white space is an issue...

Comment: So then where do you actually see the data like that? If its displayed correctly in the form after its completed

Comment: I see it when I run my python scripts on the backend to generate XML files (the whole purpose of the database) or anytime I run a select query on that column. Other identical (I think) columns behave normally, just not this one.

Comment: @pheidlauf try adding this to your server side before you insert it into the database.. python code: `your_string.replace(" ", "")`.. whatever the string is called

Comment: That's what I'll do if I can't eliminate the problem altogether. I personally suspect that I accidentally modified an encoding setting. One time, the text box in MS Access displayed in Chinese (or similar) characters.

Answer (score 0):

Questions:

- Is this happening when you enter data via Access & MySQL, or just
  Access?
- Just the via forms? How about direct table edit?
- You said it's only happening on one column? Can you delete that
  column and copy one that works?
- If only in Access queries, look at you column properties.

Comment: Just when I enter the data in access, the last update command I used manually in MySQL had no issues with the added whitespace. I have not yet tried using the linked table directly in MS Access. I have tried deleting and recreating the column several times with no luck. I'll pay more information tomorrow morning. Thanks for offering your help!